# Input onkeydown function on auto complete form

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener, onkeydown

Everything in my code works when i press enter on a form, the function executes correctly...
However, when i press enter on the auto complete portion of the form, nothing whatsoever happens, and so i have to press enter again for it to activate...

Heres my code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("form");
element.addEventListener("keydown", dothis, false);
```

and the function:

```
function dothis(e){ 
  if(e.keyCode==13){  
    alert('yey');
  }
}
```

Is there anyway for this to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an "onKeyUp" listener as well to take care of whatever is not getting handled the first time you press Enter:

> element.addEventListener("keyup", dothat, false);